# Find last letter in String using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find the regex to get the last letter in a string:

```java
String str = "A76B62Z**F**63";
```

Finding last letter via regex should return 'F'.

Comment: Please share your current code to see where the issue is.

Comment: Would `/.*([a-zA-Z])/` suffice for your needs or do more rules have to be applied to this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greedily match any sequence of characters before a letter:

```
String s = "A76B62ZF63";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*([A-Za-z])").matcher(s);
if(m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

With Java 9+:

```
String s = "A76B62ZF63";
Pattern.compile(".*([A-Za-z])").matcher(s).results()
   .findFirst().ifPresent(r -> System.out.println(r.group(1)));
```

Comment: thanks ,".*([A-Za-z])" helped

Comment: @DAVE Happy to help.